# Filter on the proxy model by field of inherited model of the proxy models parent.

Tags: python, django

I am using `Django 1.6` and using model inheritance. The title might be confusing, here is the explanation;

```
class ParentModel(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "parent_model"

    my_field=.....

class ProxyModelOfParentModel(ParentModel)
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    objects=CustomManager()


class InheritedModel(ParentModel)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "inherited_model"

    my_extra_field=.....
```

Assume that, these are our models. When I try to filter by **my_extra_field** on ParentModel, I would do it;

```
ParentModel.objects.filter(inheritedmodel__my_extra_field='test')
```

But, I want to filter on proxy model, like ;

```
ProxyModelOfParentModel.objects.filter(inheritedmodel__my_extra_field='test')
```

When I run this, it won't be able to find the field **inheritedmodel** in proxy model. This could also be bug in Django, I don't know. Somehow, django does now build the query set properly when I try to filter on proxy model.

Why I am using proxy model instead of using parent model is, using proxy models in different admins.  When I gave the key in admin `list_filter`, I met the `FieldDoesNotExists` error.

Is there a way to filter as I mention?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, this is because of django implementation for proxy model initialization. I don't know, this is bug or not but, I needed to fix this somehow. I found that it was because a part in model _meta initialization.
This part in `django.db.models.options.py` which is the part which I commented out  was causing this problem

```
def _fill_related_objects_cache(self):
    cache = SortedDict()
    parent_list = self.get_parent_list()
    for parent in self.parents:
        for obj, model in parent._meta.get_all_related_objects_with_model(include_hidden=True):
            #THIS PART WAS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
            # if (obj.field.creation_counter < 0 or obj.field.rel.parent_link) and obj.model not in parent_list:
            #     continue
            if not model:
                cache[obj] = parent
            else:
                cache[obj] = model
    # Collect also objects which are in relation to some proxy child/parent of self.
    proxy_cache = cache.copy()
    for klass in get_models(include_auto_created=True, only_installed=False):
        if not klass._meta.swapped:
            for f in klass._meta.local_fields:
                if f.rel and not isinstance(f.rel.to, six.string_types) and f.generate_reverse_relation:
                    if self == f.rel.to._meta:
                        cache[f.related] = None
                        proxy_cache[f.related] = None
                    elif self.concrete_model == f.rel.to._meta.concrete_model:
                        proxy_cache[f.related] = None
    self._related_objects_cache = cache
    self._related_objects_proxy_cache = proxy_cache
```

I just override the Options class and metaclass of my parent model instead of override Django itself like;

```
class CustomProxyModelOptions(Options):
    def _fill_related_objects_cache(self):
        cache = SortedDict()
        parent_list = self.get_parent_list()
        for parent in self.parents:
            for obj, model in parent._meta.get_all_related_objects_with_model(include_hidden=True):
                if not model:
                    cache[obj] = parent
                else:
                    cache[obj] = model
        # Collect also objects which are in relation to some proxy child/parent of self.
        proxy_cache = cache.copy()
        for klass in get_models(include_auto_created=True, only_installed=False):
            if not klass._meta.swapped:
                for f in klass._meta.local_fields:
                    if f.rel and not isinstance(f.rel.to, six.string_types) and f.generate_reverse_relation:
                        if self == f.rel.to._meta:
                            cache[f.related] = None
                            proxy_cache[f.related] = None
                        elif self.concrete_model == f.rel.to._meta.concrete_model:
                            proxy_cache[f.related] = None
        self._related_objects_cache = cache
        self._related_objects_proxy_cache = proxy_cache


class ProxyModelMeta(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        model = super(ProxyModelMeta, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        model._meta.__class__ = CustomProxyModelOptions
        return model

class ParentModel(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "parent_model"

    my_field=.....

class ProxyModelOfParentModel(ParentModel)
    __metaclass__= ProxyModelMeta
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    objects=CustomManager()


class InheritedModel(ParentModel)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "inherited_model"

    my_extra_field=.....
```

Now, I can filter;

```
ProxyModelOfParentModel.objects.filter(inheritedmodel__my_extra_field='test')
```